# Ultrawide GRUB slowness

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, display-resolution, monitor

I'm using 22.04 with a [Dell 34 inch ultrawide monitor (S3424DWC)](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-34-curved-usb-c-monitor-s3423dwc/apd/210-beje/monitors-monitor-accessories) connected to an NVIDIA 3080 by HDMI.

Here are all my installed GRUB versions (although probably unnecessary as they are all from the default 22.04 install):

```
ii  grub-common                                                 2.06-2ubuntu7.2                         amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin                                          2.06-2ubuntu14.4                        amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 modules)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-signed                                       1.187.6+2.06-2ubuntu14.4                amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
ii  grub-gfxpayload-lists                                       0.7                                     amd64        GRUB gfxpayload blacklist
ii  grub-pc                                                     2.06-2ubuntu7.2                         amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
ii  grub-pc-bin                                                 2.06-2ubuntu7.2                         amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS modules)
ii  grub2-common                                                2.06-2ubuntu7.2                         amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
```

GRUB looks amazing in the default autodetected resolution (3440x1440x32) but is really unresponsive (1-2 seconds delay to select a different item) which makes it a bit unusable.

None of the other resolutions that are available with the GRUB `videoinfo` command are superwide and all look skewed on my display (but they do respond much faster).

Is there anything I can do to speed up GRUB at my monitor's native resolution? Or can I force a slightly lower (but non-skewed) option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point of writing (3rd Feb 2024), this is a [known bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61190) in GRUB and has been reported on their bug tracking system.

The suggested fix is to set:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
```

in the GRUB configuration (`/etc/defaults/grub`), then reload with:

```
sudo grub-install
```

Hopefully, an upstream fix will arrive at some point, as higher resolution monitors become more widely available. However, this issue has been open since September 2021.